# Rails 3.1.1 , on using remote true two ajax request going to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1.1 , For using ajax in my application I used `remote=>true`  method 
on using `remote=>true` with form, my code worked fine.But, I found in firebug console  **two ajax request going to the server side.**
Even, It is not affacting my functioality but shoing two ajax request in console.
I didn't written any javascript code but only `remote=>true` 
If anybuddy has faced same issue? Or found solution regarding above?

Comment: duplicate request is shown in firebug console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That can happen if you have duplicate assets, for example you have already compiled set in the `public` folder and the initial variant in the `assets`

So try to remove the compiled assets, that helped me with exactly the same problem